# Use OrderBy in a LINQ predicate?

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

In my code I need to sort a collection either by *Price* or by *Rating.TotalGrade* and as you can see both LINQ querys are almost the same statement with only a minor difference.

I was thinking about using a LINQ predicate instead but as you can see the the *orderby* is the main difference and I found no sample using *orderby* in a query. Is it possible or are there other ways to shorten my code, Maybe there will be even more conditions in the future.

```
if (CurrentDisplayMode == CRSChartRankingGraphDisplayMode.Position)
{
    this.collectionCompleteSorted = new List<Result>(from co in collection
                                    where co.IsVirtual == false
                                    orderby co.Price, co.CurrentRanking
                                    select co);
}
else if (CurrentDisplayMode == CRSChartRankingGraphDisplayMode.Grade)
{
    this.collectionCompleteSorted = new List<Result>(from co in collection
                                    where co.IsVirtual == false
                                    orderby co.Rating.TotalGrade, co.CurrentRanking
                                    select co);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily make use of deffered nature of LINQ and ability to easily compose queries.

Probably using code like this:

```
        var baseQuery = from co in collection where !co.IsVirtual select co; // base of query
        IOrderedEnumerable<Result> orderedQuery; // result of first ordering, must be of this type, so we are able to call ThenBy

        switch(CurrentDisplayMode) // use enum here
        { // primary ordering based on enum
            case CRSChartRankingGraphDisplayMode.Position: orderedQuery = baseQuery.OrderBy(co => co.Price);
                break;
            case CRSChartRankingGraphDisplayMode.Grade: orderedQuery = baseQuery.OrderBy(co => co.TotalGrade);
                break;
        }

        this.collectionCompleteSorted = orderedQuery.ThenBy(co => co.CurrentRanking).ToList(); // secondary ordering and conversion to list
```

Its easy to understand and avoids converting to list until the very end.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! Is converting to list early a bad thing?

Comment: Its not bad. But you cant use secondary ordering using ThenBy if you convert to List too early. Also, if you are using Linq to SQL or Entities, then this will result in a query that is completly transformed into SQL. If you converted to list early, the ordering would be done on client.

Answer (score 1):

If just your order by is different, than return your result into this.collectionCompleteSorted, and then do this.collectionCompleteSorted.OrderBy() when you enumerate through the data.

```
this.collectionCompleteSorted = new List<Result>(from co in collection 
                                                             where co.IsVirtual == false                                                                  
                                                             select co);

foreach (var obj in this.collectionCompleteSorted.OrderBy(c => c.Price).ToList())
{
    // do something
}
```

And remove the order by remove your current linq query.

If the query is just being executed once, than you can leave off the .ToList() from the linq query in the example above. When ToList is called, this causes the query to be executed immediately, where if the OrderBy is implemented in a later call to the collection and a ToList is also, than the query would actually be executed on the database server with an order by statement, offloading the ordering from the code to the database. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: @Euphoric What are you talking about? The question was about how to avoid not putting an order by in the linq query. I said to use the OrderBy method call on the collection, which strangely is the same exact thing you say to do below.

Comment: So, where is your variation of different ordering based on enum value? Along with secondary ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just grab the values (less the sort), then (as it appears) use a case to order the results?

```
// build your collection first
var items = from co in collection
            where !co.IsVirtual
            select co;

// go through your sort selectors
select (CurrentDisplayMode)
{
  case CRSChartRankingGraphDisplayMode.Position:
    this.collectionCompleteSorted = items.OrderBy(i => i.Price).ThenBy(j => j.CurrentRanking).ToList();
    break;
  case CRSChartRankingGraphDisplayMode.Grade:
    this.collectionCompleteSorted = items.OrderBy(i => i.TotalGrade).ThenBy(j => j.CurrentRanking).ToList();
    break;
  ...
  //default: // maybe you want this, too
}
```

Comment: Almost there, i would recommend removing ToList from the baseQuery and perform a toList after the orderby.

Also, you have to save the result of your OrderBy again in the member, that is: this.collectionCompleteSorted = this.collectionCompleteSorted.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)

Comment: @Polity: Agreed. I fat-fingered a submit, still working out the code. ;-) Uno memento, por favor. ;p

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = collection.Where(co => !co.IsVirtual);

if (CurrentDisplayMode == CRSChartRankingGraphDisplayMode.Position)
{
    q = q.OrderBy(co => co.Price).ThenBy(co => co.CurrentRanking);
}
else if (CurrentDisplayMode == CRSChartRankingGraphDisplayMode.Grade)
{
    q = q.OrderBy(co => co.Rating.TotalGrade).ThenBy(co => co.CurrentRanking);
}

this.collectionCompleteSorted = q.ToList();
```

Comment: You wont be able to call ThenBy on q, because q will be inferred ad IEnumerable<> and not IOrderedEnumerable<>